# Laravel render dropdown list from related table under employee table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables. Employee table and Roles tables. In my employee.show blade I want to render the dropdown list of the role already assgined or available to assign. I am not using collective forms and am a little stuck as all tutorials use thse.

My controller

```
 public function show($employee)
 {
     $employee = Employees::find($employee); 
     $roles = Roles::pluck('role_name', 'id'); 
 return view('employees.show')->withEmployee($employee)->withRoles($roles);
}
```

and my show.blade. Question is how do i pull the complete list from db of all other roles so a user can update?

```
   <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="roles_id">Role</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select id="roles_id" name="roles_id" class="form-control">
<option value="{{ $employee->roles->id }}">{{ $employee->roles->role_name }}</option>
</select>            
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking you want to create a dropdown list of all the available roles from your database, but pre-select the list with the user's current role if any?

Comment: Yes please.@Jonathon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done in your controller seems correct. Your view however should loop through the roles and create options for them. Bear in mind, that you've used `Role::pluck('role_name', 'id')`, which will return an array of `'id' => 'role_name'`.

You can decide which one is selected by adding a selected attribute to the employee's role option by using a ternary statement, which compare's the employee's `role_id` to the `role_id` we're currently looking at in the loop.

Try something like this:

```
<select name="roles_id">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    @foreach ($roles as $roleId => $roleName)
        <option value="{{ $roleId }}"{!! $employee->role_id == $roleId ? ' selected' : '' !!}>{{ $roleName }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked first time.

 Presumably where you have roleID it means the same as role_id. I have amended so pattern is consistent across views. 
thanks again. #

Comment: No problem. The `@foreach` pretty much translates to a PHP `foreach` statement where you can have `$key => $value` so `$roleId` there refers to the key of the array returned by `pluck` which in your case will refer to the `id` of the `Role` object.